# How to read the large text files efficiently in java

Tags: java, file

Here, I am reading the 18 MB file and store it in a two dimensional array. But this program takes almost 15 minutes to run. Is there anyway to optimize the running time of the program. The file contains only binary values. Thanks in advance…

```
public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader br;

        FileReader fr=null;
        int m = 2160;
        int n = 4320;
        int[][] lof = new int[n][m];
        String filename = "D:/New Folder/ETOPOCHAR";
       try {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("D:/New Folder/ETOPOCHAR"));
        double range_km=1.0;
        double alonn=-57.07; //180 to 180
        double alat=38.53;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                   try
                   {
                      lof[j][i] = input.nextInt();
                      System.out.println("value[" + j + "][" + i + "] = "+ lof[j][i]);
                    }
                   catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                      //  e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }         //print the input matrix
        }
```

I have also tried with byte array  but i can not save it in twoD array...

```
public class FileToArrayOfBytes
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

        File file = new File("name of file");

        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            //convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((char)bFile[i]);
            }

        System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `contains only binary values` I guess this means it contains `01100` and not that the file is in binary format, right?

Comment: yes..it contains only 0 1 values.

Comment: Have you tried `Files.readAllLines`? If yes, is the loss of speed due to the file-reading or the population of the array?

Comment: I am not sure ... but the scanner's constructor taking a file simply opens a `FileInputStream` on that file. This should be buffered, especially for large files. So maybe you should use `new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("D:/New Folder/ETOPOCHAR"))))`

Comment: yes i have used it but the value can not be assign in 2 d Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a byte array first, then deserialize these bytes. Start with 2048 bytes buffer (as input buffer), then experiment by increasing/decreasing its size, but the experimental buffer size values should be a power of two (512, 1024, 2048, etc). 
As far as I rememenber, there are good chances that the best performance can be achived with a buffer of size 2048 bytes, but it is OS dependent and should be verified.

Code sample (here you can try different values of BUFFER_SIZE variable, in my case I've read a test file of size 7.5M in less then one second):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) f.length());
    try (FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(f)) {
      int bytesRead;
      int totalBytesRead = 0;
      while ((bytesRead = fos.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
        result.put(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
      }
      // debug info
      System.out.printf("Read %d bytes\n", totalBytesRead);

      // Here you can do whatever you want with the result, including creation of a 2D array...
      int pos = result.position();
      result.rewind();
      for (int i = 0; i < pos / 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(result.getInt());
      }
    }
  }
```

Take your time and read docs for java.io, java.nio packages as well as Scanner class, just to improve understanding.

Comment: I have tried this but i can not assign the value in 2 d array..can you please provide the sample code for this.

Comment: First of all, you have an error in your code sample. I add a code sample to my answer.

Comment: @Ivan...I have tried your code..but in result.getint(), i have got some byte value..how can I get the value of file..My file contains 0 or 1 value

Comment: Have you read javadocs of the ByteBuffer? getInt() method is just an example, that you can fetch data in a loop using appropriate getXXX method. Zeros and ones have their representation, for example "1" can be represented by: 01 or 0001 or even 0100 (depends on endianness). This is up to you to understand the format and apply appropriate getter.

Comment: yes, I have seen other methods also like result.get()..but it returns some values but not file contents...

Comment: bhagyasri patel, this is a completely different question, which is unrelated with file reading optimizations.